# Flutter how to check if product is already added to the basket

Tags: flutter, controller

I am trying to check if the product  already added to the basket and give the message with snackbar "This product already added". So user can not add the  same product to the cart again.

here is the code of mine :

```
//Button calling controller adding item to cart
InkWell(
  onTap:(){
   _con.addItemToCart(_con.product);
});


//Controller adding item to cart 
  Future addItemToCart(Product product, {bool reset = false}) async {
    setState(() {
      this.loadCart = true;
    });
    Cart value =
        await addToCart(product, scaffoldKey, context, quantity: quantity);
    setState(() {
      this.cart = value;
      this.loadCart = false;
      this.totalProductsInStock = this.product.availability;
      this.totalProductsInStock -= this.totalProductsInStock - this.quantity ;
    });
  }


 Future<Cart> addToCart(Product product, GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey, BuildContext buildContext, {bool reset = false, int quantity = 1}) async {
      var _cartPoduct = new CartProduct();
      _cartPoduct.productId = product.id;
      _cartPoduct.optionId = product.optionId;
      _cartPoduct.quantity = quantity;
      Cart value = await CartRepository.addCart(_cartPoduct, reset);
      return value;
    }


//Request
  static Future<Cart> addCart(CartProduct cartProduct, bool reset) async {
    User _user = userRepo.currentUser.value;
    if (_user.apiToken == null) {
      return new Cart();
    }
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedJSON = {};
    cartProduct.userId = _user.id;
    final String url =
        '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}';
    final client = new http.Client();
    final response = await client
        .get(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'});
    try {
      decodedJSON = json.decode(response.body)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
    }
    return Cart.fromJSON(decodedJSON);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a temporary list to check if the product has been added to the cart, and I have it checked with provider. You can check it maybe it will be useful for you
[link](https://github.com/hsynshnl/ShoppingCartWithProvider)